# PHP - Get the Opposite of Logical Operator If test

Tags: php, if-statement, logical-operators

I have a simple test to determine if there is no overlap between 2 date ranges as follows:

```
          if(strtotime($endDateA) <= strtotime(trim($startDateB)) or strtotime($startDateA) >= strtotime(trim($endDateB))) {
          }
```

If one of these is true then the 2 date ranges do not overlap. I now need to flip this to get the opposite but I'm not sure how to go about this using the ! or the || operators.

I don't have much experience with these in PHP and haven't been able to get anything working so far. In other languages I would normally do something like this:

```
(EndA <= StartB or StartA >= EndB) // original test
NOT (EndA <= StartB or StartA >= EndB) // opposite test
```

but I can't work out how to do the same in PHP.

Comment: `if( ! (strtotime($endDateA) <= strtotime(trim($startDateB)) or strtotime($startDateA) >= strtotime(trim($endDateB))))`

Comment: Also: trim is not needed, strtotime ignores surrounding spaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to invert any logic statement such as

```
if(strtotime($endDateA) <= strtotime(trim($startDateB)) 
    or strtotime($startDateA) >= strtotime(trim($endDateB)))
```

you can use `!` to invert the whole thing, but this can make it very difficult to understand (IMHO).

If you invert the condition - so `<=` becomes `>`, `>=` becomes `<` and flip the `or` to an `and`, this gives you

```
if(strtotime($endDateA) > strtotime(trim($startDateB)) 
    and strtotime($startDateA) < strtotime(trim($endDateB)))
```